# How can I programaticly open Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

I want to edit content in frontend and backend with the Gutenberg editor in a popup window.
I pass the content to the editor with JavaScript, open it, edit the content in Gutenberg and when I close it I pass the content to a variable again.

Now several questions arise:

- When loading WordPress with a page without page or cpt-page wp.data/wp.block is not loaded. Also not with the plugin "Gutenberg Ramp" with which Gutenberg should always be loaded.

Therefore the question, is there a possibility to load Gutenberg with the hook init?

If so, how do I start Gutenberg proramaticly?

Many thanks for tips

Severin

Comment: I built Frontenberg, and tried to do exactly what you're asking. TLDR: Don't. To get it to work I had to heavily lock down the REST API so no saving could happen, and the theme was basically WP Admin styles only. Even then, it still has major issues, such as changing the URL to `wp-admin` URLs. Making it appear in a popup and actually using it as a frontend editor is a complete nonstarter. What you're asking is non-trivial and a **huge** task. Avoid this like the plague

Comment: Many thanks @tom-j-nowell
 i just read your post [how frontenberg works](https://tomjn.com/2018/01/22/how-frontenberg-works/) yes there are many unknown ones. In my case there would be the simplification that the users are always logged in. This is simpler but still very complex.

Comment: That your users are logged in helps, but GB just wasn't built for what you want, so unless you're a very experienced React developer who has the time to redo a lot of it every release I wouldn't even attempt it. Frontenberg is more of a kludge, definitely not a production ready thing

Comment: I had hoped that there would be a similar solution to opening the media overview with wp.media().
This case with Gutenberg is not possible because of my skills.
I will make a button with link to the edit page. Not very nice but feasible.